# Couchbase .net bulk insert

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I'm trying to do a bulk read/write performance tests on couchbase and a couple other products but it doesn't look like I can do bulk-insert with couchbase. Does couchbase .net (1.8) support bulk-insert?

Thank you,

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The Couchbase .NET Client doesn't currently support bulk inserts.  There are some approaches you can use with the client as-is to perform bulk loads.  I've documented those at the link below (see "Bulk Loading").

http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Couchbase+.NET+Client+Library#Couchbase.NETClientLibrary-BulkLoading

One thing to keep in mind is that the .NET client doesn't currently support SetQ operations, which are optimal for multi-sets.  That operation is queued up for the 1.3 release of the client.  The standard Set operation should provide more than acceptable performance for bulk data loads.